# Exclude nested tables from table striping with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, jquery-selectors

I am trying to exclude nested tables from my table striping (making every other row a different bg color). Here is my code to stripe the table:

```
$(".stripeTable tbody tr:odd").addClass("stripe");
```

My question is, how to I prevent the nested table's odd rows from receiving the class "stripe"?

Here's the generated code from the browser, I want to remove the class="stripe" from the nested table.

```
   <table>
      <tr>
        <td>My Table Cell </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="stripe">
        <td>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>My nested table cell</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="stripe">
              <td>my nested table cell (remove the stripe!)</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Where is the `stripeTable` class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If only the top-level table has the `stripeTable` class, just add some child selectors `>`:

```
$(".stripeTable > tbody > tr:odd").addClass("stripe");
```

If the nested tables have the `stripeTable` class as well, you may need to anchor `.stripeTable` to another parent element with another child selector:

```
$(".parent > .stripeTable > tbody > tr:odd").addClass("stripe");
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I had a ">" before the tbody, but I see now that it needs it before the tr too.

Comment: Yes as you have nested `tr`s too, so they'd get selected otherwise.